# Is it possible to close/reopen connection using pd.read_sql and chunking?

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say I have a very large table and I want to use pd.read_sql with chunksize = 10000.

The way I approach it now is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('dialect://user:pass@host:port/schema')
with engine.connect() as conn:
  for df in pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM VERY_LARGE_TABLE', con=conn, chunksize=10000):
    do stuff
```

My issue here (with snowflake as a data source) is that the connection will expire midway through "do stuff".

Is it possible to do something like:

```
engine = create_engine('dialect://user:pass@host:port/schema', echo=False)
# chunk 1
with engine.connect() as conn:
  df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM VERY_LARGE_TABLE', con=conn)
do stuff

# chunk 2
with engine.connect() as conn:
  df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM VERY_LARGE_TABLE', con=conn)
do stuff
```

The alternative I'm exploring right now is setting `connect_args={"client_session_keep_alive": True}` in the engine

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like:

```
start = 0
chunk = 5000

while True:

    with engine.connect() as conn:
        query = f'SELECT * FROM VERY_LARGE_TABLE LIMIT {start}, {chunk}'
        df = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
    
        # if df is empty stop querying
        if df.empty: 
            break
        else:         # increase start for next iteration
            start += chunk
        
    do stuff
```